# Pass Camera OnActivityResult to Webservice to be Saved on Server as Image

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

So I've gotten as far as getting the camera to open, take the picture and then return the camera result as follows:

```
bt.Click += delegate
   {
      Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
      StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
   };
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Result.Ok && requestCode == 0)
        {
            string result = data.ToURI();            
        }
```

The value of result ends up as "#Intent;action=inline-data;B.bitmap-data=true;end".  I don't really know where to go from here as far as taking the picture result and being able to turn it over to my web-service that will then save it as an image file on the server.

Edit:  The final code for anyone with the same problem

```
bt.Click += delegate
   {
  Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
  StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
  };
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
 {
    Bitmap bitmap = (Android.Graphics.Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");

    using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
      bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
      byte[] imageBytes = stream.ToArray();
      string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

      inst.saveImage(base64String);
    }
 }
    [WebMethod]
    public void saveImage(string stream)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(stream);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
          imageBytes.Length);
        var filepath = "C:\\Temp\\Test.png";

        using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(filepath))
        {
            ms.CopyTo(file, (int)stream.Length);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you get back includes the bitmap data, as your "result" string shows. You can pull the bitmap out of the Intent and compress it out to a stream by doing something like this:

```
var bitmap = (Android.Graphics.Bitmap) data.Extras.Get("data");

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);

    // stream now contains the image data
}
```

You can use any type of .NET stream there, so the MemoryStream is just an example.

Comment: The var bitmap = (Android.Graphics.Bitmap)data.GetStringExtra("data"); line is producing a null reference exception.

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't mean to call GetStringExtra when it's obviously not a string...updated.

Comment: Not getting the null reference error anymore.  But still not sure stream contains anything.  When passing the stream to the webservice to be saved, I need to convert stream to a string (Was having a crazy type mismatch situation when I leave it as a stream).  When I do StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);   string text = reader.ReadToEnd();  text is empty.

Comment: That's because the stream's pointer is at the end of the stream. Run this before reading the stream to move it back to the beginning:

stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Comment: The value of text now comes to �PNG\r\n\n and when I pass it to the webservice and do
        public void saveImage(string streams)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(streams);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            var filepath = "C:\\Temp\\Test.png";
            using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(filepath))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(file, (int)stream.Length);
            }
        }  I get The request failed with HTTP status 400: BadRequest

Comment: You're getting outside the scope of the question now (and this isn't the best place to have a discussion). Once you have the bytes from the image (I don't see a need to convert it to a string either), you can send that over the wire to your service. If there's an error in that transmission, that's a separate issue.

Comment: My question was specifically getting the camera results to a point where I could pass to webservice and save as image.  I haven't got that to happen yet so I'm not sure how I am getting outside the scope of the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6821/discussion-between-greg-shackles-and-jmease)